# Can you throw a generic exception?

Tags: java, exception

Is it possible to define a generic method that throws an exception of type to be defined by the generic parameter?

I have a suite of exceptions, derived from a common exception `Foo` that has a constructor to a string. My trial code

```
public <T/*an exception that can be constructed from a string*/> void foo() throws T
{
    // try something
    throw new T("Hello");
}
```

doesn't compile with error:

> T cannot be converted to Throwable

Comment: You need to specify that `T` must be "throwable" then?

Comment: @nbro Step in the right direction, but will still fail on `new T()`

Comment: `T` is a type parameter. `new T()` doesn't make sense because `T` might be an interface, or a class without a public constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the duplicate Nathan Hughes. I wonder why this site doesn't allow you to earn reputation on that spot.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate of the linked question. This question is about type parameters which are Throwable, whereas the linked question is about Throwables with type parameters.